# How can I get the interval start and end of a groupby.agg function when the timestamp is the index?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

DataFrame example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

days = pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00:00','2020-01-02 00:00:00',freq='1S')
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
category = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],  size=len(days))

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': days, 'category': category, 'data': data})
df = df.set_index('time')
df
```

Output:

```py
                    category  data
time                              
2020-01-01 00:00:00        B    27
2020-01-01 00:00:01        D    10
2020-01-01 00:00:02        D    87
2020-01-01 00:00:03        B    78
2020-01-01 00:00:04        A    49
2020-01-01 00:00:05        C    21
2020-01-01 00:00:06        C    32
2020-01-01 00:00:07        A    95
2020-01-01 00:00:08        B    75
2020-01-01 00:00:09        B    19
                     ...   ...
2020-01-01 23:59:51        D     9
2020-01-01 23:59:52        D    67
2020-01-01 23:59:53        B    57
2020-01-01 23:59:54        D    51
2020-01-01 23:59:55        A    75
2020-01-01 23:59:56        D    47
2020-01-01 23:59:57        B    19
2020-01-01 23:59:58        A    90
2020-01-01 23:59:59        D     7
2020-01-02 00:00:00        B    44

[86401 rows x 2 columns]
```

I'd like to calculate for each category the min, max, average of DATA, but also the MIN and MAX timestamp. However, since the timestamp is the index, I don't now how to to that. I'm getting:

```py
df.groupby('category').agg({'time': [min, max], 'data': [np.min, np.max, np.average]})

KeyError: "Column 'time' does not exist!"
```

If I remove the "'time': [min, max]", it works:

```py
         data                
         amin amax    average
category                     
A           1   99  50.072437
B           1   99  49.542499
C           1   99  50.291096
D           1   99  49.851255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the index and groupby and it doesn't matter cause the after groupby the index doesn't exist.

```
df.reset_index().groupby('category').agg({'time': [min, max], 'data': [np.min, np.max, np.average]})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which parameter I should use to get the "mode" also? min, max, average and mode (tried np.mode, doesn't exist).

Comment: I know it's late but you can use `pd.Series.mode` from pandas or `scipy.stats.mode` from scipy package